# How to check if the iOS app was build with Xcode 10 or Xcode 11

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to check the builds for iOS apps and check if the app was build using Xcode 10 or Xcode 11 or any other version of Xcode. Can anybody guide me on how can I achieve this case?

Comment: You mean archives ??

Comment: @NavneetKaur yes archives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I got the answer, we can check this by opening the .xarchive file by show package contents and the Products>Applications>_.app show package contents and then check Info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

please check the screenshot. to check the archives of Xcode 11 you need to check organiser of Xcode 11 and similarly for Xcode 10 you must open organiser of Xcode 10.[image: please check]

Comment: I want to find the difference between the archives of Xcode 11 and Xcode 10, I can find the archives in the organizer but how to find the difference between archives?

Comment: Hey .. if you've opened the organiser from Xcode 11 it will show archives of Xcode 11 only ..

Comment: No, it shows me archives of all the versions of Xcode used till now.